# Filter dates in sharepoint list with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I just created a workflow using Sharepoint Designer 2013 and I getting  the error shown in yellow

[image]

What do I have to change in the **Call HTTP web Service** string builder to make it work?

regards, Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Designer, you often have to encode the spaces (%20) in the filter so that it knows not to cut off the url. Also, it is generally best practice in ODATA filter comparisons to wrap a datetime value with `datetime('somedatestringhere')` to ensure it gets interpreted and compared as a date value and not as a text value.

So, your URI should look something like `[%Variable: SiteUrl%]_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<sitelist>')/Items?$filter=Data%20ge%20datetime('[%Variable: DataIni%]')`